# Preg_match блокирует латиницу. Кириллицу пропускает

Tags: php

```
    if (preg_match("/^[а-яА-Яa-zA-Z0-9\s?!,.'Ёё]+$/", $message)) 
        return "Можно использовать только символы английского и русского алфавита.";
```

Смысл был в том, чтобы люди не могли спамить всякими греческими и т.д. символами. Таким образом они обходили защиту от спама. Но теперь вообще можно писать только русскими буквами(кириллицей). На латиницу срабатывает прегматч и людям выводит сообщение.

Не могу понять в чем косяк.

Comment: Условие и текст в return строго противоречат друг другу. В условии написано, что `$message` состоит только из указанных байт (к слову про байты - модификатор u забыт, вы ведь явно про юникод, в однобайтовых кодировках одновременно греческого и кириллицы не бывает).

Answer (score 0):

Изменить регулярное выражение на **^[а-яА-Я0-9\s?!,.'Ёё]+$** изменить условие if
Должно так работать:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[а-яА-Я0-9\s?!,.'Ёё]+$/", $message)) 
    return "Можно использовать только символы английского и русского алфавита.";
```

Comment: Так вроде ваше условие только русские символы пропускает. Или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: @МаркМойсеев Да, все верно